# how to extract a subset of a dataframe where the date column is larger than a date?

Tags: python, pandas, subset, slice

I have a dataframe consist of a date column and other columns.
as a sample see the below,

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2021/2/21', '2021/2/20','2021/3/5','2021/5/30'],
            'Number':[2,4,6,9]})

a

      Date   Number
0   2021/2/21   2
1   2021/2/20   4
2   2021/3/5    6
3   2021/5/30   9
```

a['Date'].dtypes
Object

neither of the following got me the subset

```
a = a[a['Date'] > '20/02/2021']
[x for x in a['Date'] if x > '20/02/2021' ]
```

how can I get the subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and standardize date column

```
a['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(a.Date)
```

Then compare using `ge` i.e. greater than

```
a['Date'].ge('2021/02/21')
```